# Getting a dictionary var from parsed json in swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode

i'm trying to set all the parsed information in json in a dict variable but it returns an empty dict. when i get the array value, everything works completely fine. 
here is my code:

```
let dic = json.arrayValue

                                for each in dic {
                            let data = each["data"].dictionaryValue
                               print (data)
                                    let date = each["date"].stringValue
                                   print (date)
}
```

parsing date works fine too. and note that my json file is not empty. because when i get the arrayValue everything is fine. here is the output when i `print each["data"].arrayValue`:

```
[{
  "factoryPrice" : 0,
  "size" : 25,
  "t5" : 0,
  "t3" : 0,
  "type" : 1,
  "bongahPrice" : 2435,
  "sherkat" : "",
  "priceConfirmed" : 1,
  "id" : 1658,
  "factory" : 9,
  "exist" : true,
  "t1" : 0,
  "provice" : 1,
  "properties" : {
    "طول" : "12 متری",
    "info" : "",
    "استاندارد" : "A2",
    "standard" : "A3",
    "رنگ" : "مشکی",
    "نوع" : "آجدار"
  },
  "factoryName" : "نیشابور",
  "city" : 306,
  "name" : "",
  "phoneNumber" : "09338810407",
  "createdAt" : "2018-02-16 12:52:50",
  "ownerId" : 282,
  "shomareSabt" : "",
  "t4" : 0,
  "profileType" : 0,
  "t2" : 0,
  "modirName" : "آرزومند",
  "bongahName" : "میلگرد تهران",
  "updatedAt" : "11:36",
  "weight" : 22,
  "group" : 57,
  "bongahAddress" : "بازاراهن شادباد بوستان بلوک  B",
  "bongahPhone" : "02166139083"
}]
```

and this only one of the arrays. i get multiple arrays in response. 
so what should i do?

Comment: @Moritz when i get array value it works completely fine. that's not the problem. also like i mentioned, date output is okay too. please read the question before answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you have has an array as its top level element. This is clear by the first character: `[`.

You can't directly get a dictionary value for your JSON because it represents an array. That's the reason trying to get `dictionaryValue` returns `nil`.